# How to set an immutable member after struct default construction?

Tags: struct, d, immutability, copy-constructor

I have a struct whose one of the member is immutable so it can only be initialized in a constructor. However since it's a struct, an instance can be declared without calling a constructor and then initialized later using a copy constructor (or any other function).

Problem: the call is forbidden by the compiler since the immutable member is supposed to be already set.

Demonstration of the problem:

```
struct Member
{
    immutable int value;
}

struct Foo
{
    Member memb;
    this(string param)
    {
        memb = Member(1);
    }
    void reset(string name){}
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    // here error
    Foo foo;
    foo = Foo("test");

    // here memb is never set
    Foo bar; 
    bar.reset("test");
}
```

In the real life application, what happens is the second case. No error is generated but the program doesn't work well because the immutable member has not been set properly.

I could use a class (because in classes the default constructor can be rewritten) but I don't want to because the struct is more a less POD.

**edit**

Important detail:The parameter to call the struct constructor directly are not all directly available. This is not well represented in the demo.

Comment: That should be the job of a plain initial constructor, not copy constructor. Because even with custom (non`.init`) constructors how'd you assign an `immutable` member field inside the constructor?

Comment: Yes but _plain initial constructors_ don't exist in D struct (e.g `this(){}`).

Comment: Actually, by "plain initial" I meant any `this(args...)` vs `this(this)`.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean and edited the Q. The parameters to call the constructor are not all available at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `@disable this();` is for - disabling the default constructor, forcing it to be constructed explicitly at the declaration site (or, in the constructor of a containing aggregate; e.g. the constructor of a class if your struct is a member).

While you cannot define a default constructor, you can disable it and force the user to use one of your other constructors or static factory methods. Do that and make them set the immutable member.